# Trigger dows not let me insert data in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

i am trying to get used to triggers. I created a small database and a trigger. When i go to insert something in ship category it does not let me do it.If i drop the trigger with the same commend i can insert values at the table. I get this error: #1048 - Column 'IMO' cannot be null
My trigger code is:

```
/*ship insert*/
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `ship_insert_logs` 
AFTER INSERT ON `ship` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE ship_IMO INTEGER;
SET ship_IMO=new.IMO; 
INSERT INTO ship_logs VALUES (null, concat('A new row is inserted with IMO ', ship_IMO, 'at', 
date_format(now(), '%d-%m-%y %h:%i:%s %p')));
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and ship table is:

```
CREATE TABLE ship(      
department_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
IMO BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Latitude DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
Longitude DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
current_speed DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
heading VARCHAR (30),
status VARCHAR(30), 
FOREIGN KEY(department_id) REFERENCES department (department_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

while ship_logs table is:

```
CREATE TABLE ship_logs(      
IMO BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
audit_description VARCHAR(500)
);
```

Comment: Please add an example on an insert to ship.

Comment: INSERT INTO ship(department_id,IMO,Latitude, Longitude,current_speed, heading, status) VALUES (2, 9171448, 1.5915, 104.5291, 0.0, 'SINGAPORE [SG]', 'At Anchor');

Comment: You forget to define `ship_logs.IMO` as AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The insert in the trigger is setting imo to null - is that what you wanted to do? or did you want to set it to new.imo? or did you want it to be an auto_increment column?

Comment: I wanted to set it to new.IMO

Comment: thanks guys i found my mistake! in the trigger i was setting it to null and i made IMO not null in the table.